# f1 or accuracy scoring after downsampling - classification, svm - Python

Tags: python, classification

I have a dataset consisting in 15 columns and 3000 rows to train a model for a binary classification. 
There is a imbalance for y (1:2). Both outcomes (0,1) are equally important.

After downsampling (because the parameter class_weight = balanced didn't work well), I used the parameter scoring = "f1", because I read that this was next to the ROC curve the best measurement of the performance.

The question is: 
Do I treat my data after downsampling still as unbalanced and therefore apply f1 or can I go back to normal accuracy?

f1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

Cheers in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've rebalanced your data, then it's not unbalanced anymore and I see no problem with using accuracy as the success metric.

Accuracy can mislead you in very skewed datasets but since it isn't skewed anymore, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! 

My takeaway from this is, that I first check whether the imbalance is remediable. If this is the case, I will downsample/upsample and use accuracy as measurement. Otherwise I leave the data and use the f1/ROC.

If using the class_weight = 'balanced' I would treat this case as if I had had rebalanced the data.